# Vertical Justification of Elements of Enumerate Environment?

Tags: spacing, lists, vertical-alignment, enumerate

How do I automatically vertically justify (evenly vertically space in a page) the `\item`s of an `enumerate` environment?

Is adding `\vfill` after each `\item` the only way to do this?

Comment: The space between items is `\itemsep` so you can make that stretchy either in a redefinition, or using `enumitem` package in an optional argument on specific lists

Comment: if one read this literally, i.e. that the beginning of each item is to be the exact same distance from every adjacent item, this is going to be really difficult unless every item occupies exactly the same number of lines.  is that what is meant?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`enumitem` is your friend:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[pass,showframe]{geometry} % show a frame around the page
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newenvironment{spreadenum}[1][]
  {\begin{enumerate}[itemsep=.6ex plus 1fill,#1]}
  {\end{enumerate}\par\vfill}

\begin{document}

\begin{spreadenum}
\item a
\item b
\item c
\item d
\end{spreadenum}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The spacing of top level lists at normalsize in the default 10pt option in the standard classes is set by

```
\makeatletter
\def\@listi{\leftmargin\leftmargini
            \parsep 4\p@ \@plus2\p@ \@minus\p@
            \topsep 8\p@ \@plus2\p@ \@minus4\p@
            \itemsep4\p@ \@plus2\p@ \@minus\p@}
\let\@listI\@listi
\makeatother
```

(in `size10.clo`) so the vertical stretch is by default limited to 2pt, you could change that to `5in` or `\fill` or whatever you need in the preamble if you want a global change/